# Intrinsic definition of arc length

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves

Given a Riemannian manifold $\mathcal M$ with metric $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, we define the length of a smooth curve $\gamma : I \to \mathcal M$ as
\begin{equation}
L(\gamma) = \int_I \sqrt{\langle \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle}_{\gamma(t)} \ \text{d}t.
\end{equation}
Why are we allowed to do this, and not define the differential of a smooth map $F : \mathcal M \to \mathcal N$ by $\text{d}F_p : \gamma'(0) \mapsto (F \circ \gamma)'(0)$? I'm restricted to the non-embedded case here.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Please clarify/elaborate.

Comment: @TedShifrin Isn’t the whole reason for defining tangent vectors as derivations or equivalence classes of curves to avoid writing things like $\gamma’(t)$ when the manifold is not embedded in Euclidean space? Why is this okay for the definition of arc length?

Comment: No, that is most certainly not the point. The tangent vector of a curve is a tangent vector, independent of the particular definition one uses of the tangent space.

Comment: @TedShifrin Then why can’t we simply define tangent vectors once and for all by velocities of curves on the manifold?

Comment: One of the definitions of $\gamma’(t)$, in the manifold case, **is** as the equivalence class of curves. It is not a limit of a difference quotient (since that’s meaningless in general). It’s just the way we choose our notation. But still, I’m not sure what your question actually is.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I was under the impression that the reason for defining tangent vectors as equivalence classes is to obtain an “intrinsic” formulation of tangent spaces. I’m just comparing it to the arc length definition, and seeing $\gamma’(t)$ makes me a little uneasy. Why go through all the hassle of equivalence classes if we just end up taking the derivative anyway?

Comment: Because until you have a well-defined notion of the tangent space, you can't talk about things that belong to it?

Comment: ^ and you can’t talk about derivatives in the manifold setting without first defining tangent spaces. You can’t say “oh why bother if we’re just going to take the derivative”. I think you’re suffering from the very understandable issue that the notation is meant to evoke familiarity, but the order of development is somewhat altered.

Comment: How would you define $\gamma'(t)$?

Comment: Saying $$ dF_p(\gamma'(0)) = (F\circ\gamma)'(0) $$ looks correct to me.

Comment: By the way, if you were to take the derivations approach to defining tangent vectors, then, indeed, you would define $v=\gamma'(0)$ to be the tangent vector at $p=\gamma(0)$ with the property that $v(f) = (f\circ\gamma)'(0)$ for any smooth scalar-valued $f$. Looks familiar, eh?